# TFS automated test add artifact - source

Tags: tfs, winappdriver

I have a whole Visual Studio project full of Window Application Driver automated tests. They work, they launch the application from it's executable in windows 10, login and test things...

I want to link these Test Methods (within ordered tests in my VS project) to TFS Test Cases in my TFS test plan. I'm using the TFS web Portal and to link my tests, I am following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops).

I get to step 8 and my "Add artifact" dialog doesn't look like the one in the example. I think at this step we are trying to add the test project dll that has been built for my test project in Visual Studio. Is that correct and how do I add it?

My screen doesn't look like the example, it looks like this ...

[image]

Comment: What's your TFS version?

Answer (score 0):

To Run automated tests from test plans, please first meet below preconditions:

- A test plan containing your automated tests, which you have
  associated with automated test methods using Visual Studio 2017, or
  Visual Studio 2015 or earlier.
- A Team Build pipeline that generates builds containing the test
  binaries.
- The app to test. You can deploy the app as part of the build and
  release workflow and also use it for on-demand testing.

You must also be a Project Contributor, or have some permissions.

Yes, just as the tutorial for step 8. In release pipeline, you need to verify that the build pipeline containing **the test binaries is linked to this release pipeline as an artifact source**.

To add it, you should select the corresponding build pipeline first, if we not select the pipeline, will get the same screenshot as your side.

[image]

However, after select one pipeline, it will be the same as the tutorial, you could also be able to change Default Version and Source Alias

[image]

***Note:*** For different versions of TFS, the UI may not be totally the same. Besides, TFS 2015 is not supported.

Comment: I have managed to do it now, my TFS administrator at work managed to pick his was through the Microsoft documentation and work out what is and is not applicable in our situation. I think that what MS are trying to guide people towards is automated deployment followed by test. That wasn't what we wanted but as the MS guides don't make that clear it did throw us a bit. MS also assume a lot of previous experience.